# Population of sublevels after Zeeman effect appearance

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, spectroscopy

I have following question. We have a single atom and an ability to excite its electron from ground state, the system is closed. Assume, at instant time, I populate whatever level $ ^ NP_1 $ which has a degenerate sublevels as $ ^ NP _ {- 1,0,1} $. So, now I turn magnetic field and want to observe the population of each sublevels which are not degenerate already due Zeeman effect. What one can expect? What probability is AND how to calculate this in order to find the expected population of sublevels?

My intuition tells the answer is beyond naive answer where we find electron at any sublevels with probability of 1/3. I would expect there is a connection between sublevels population and how we turn magnetic field like "quick" (instant) or adiabatically.

I am awaiting for links you support me to read or even few lines of your comments on my, I presume, stupid question.

P.S. I did not work with atomic spectroscopy for one decade almost,therefore forgot too much already. Do not treat the question to serious, there is no pitfalls in it, at least I did not plan them.

Comment: Depends on the polarisation on the light causing the transition. Look up selection  rules.

Comment: Then, you need a quantization axis which is undefined before magnetic field (MF) applying (correct me if I am wrong). How can you guarantee the sublevel with a given total angular momentum is being preserved populated by the MF swithing on and wont be changed ?

As far as I understand the conservation law  will not be violated as soon as total angular momentum is preserved and only projection is varying.

Comment: So it became clear now. After photon interacted with an atom and transfers momentum to an electron. The last one starts orbital rotation corresponding to the inherited momentum exhibiting no changes due to momentum conservation law. Once we switch magnetic field, the quantization axis is being determined and we just project the angular momentum to the new basis obtained. The scalar product will bring us an amplitude probability to find each of sublevels populated.